# Underscore plus numeric sequence value being appended to end of element id

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, repeater

Does anybody know why this would be happening?

I have an aspx page that has data populated by a repeater. For some reason a numeric sequence value is being appended to all element ids that are being created by .net. Examples of element ids.

```
id="SearchResults_rep_ChkBoxSelectRecord_ID_100001_0"
id="SearchResults_rep_ChkBoxSelectRecord_ID_100002_1"
id="SearchResults_rep_ChkBoxSelectRecord_ID_100003_2"
id="SearchResults_rep_ChkBoxSelectRecord_ID_100004_3"
```

However, the element names do not have the extra value appended:

```
name="SearchResults_rep_ChkBoxSelectRecord_ID_100001"
name="SearchResults_rep_ChkBoxSelectRecord_ID_100002"
name="SearchResults_rep_ChkBoxSelectRecord_ID_100003"
name="SearchResults_rep_ChkBoxSelectRecord_ID_100004"
```

The ids are assigned dynamically in the codebehind from an integer. ...and this does not happen when running locally, but is happening on our staging server. I am aware of the ClientIDMode if I wanted to not use the .net id auto naming convention, but it would require too many code changes if I changed that property now. I am running into wall as to why this is happening. Any ideas?

More info in case it is relevant. The staging server is running Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6

Comment: Should your second example have name=".." instead of id="..."? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Great :) Are these checkboxes part of a CheckBoxList?

Comment: @KristianFrost No, they are not, they get populated inside a table that is created by a repeater in codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up discovering a solution to this issue, it had to do with upgrading code from .net 2.0 to 4.0 and the default value of the ClientIDMode, which for .net 4.0 is `Predictable`.

Adding `<pages clientIDMode="AutoID">` to the `System.Web` node in the web.config resolved the issue.